# c# sum of the sums in the array

Tags: c#

Got stuck on quite simple problem in my code. I need to count what I would call a nested sums of an array. Let's take as an example the array:
`[1,2,2,3,6]`
I want to sum them as:

```
0 + 1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 + 2 = 5
1 + 2 + 2 + 3 = 8
1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 6 = 14

sum = 1 + 3 + 5 + 8 + 14 = 31
```

Edit:
I tried to do it with stack, but it failed

```
            int sums = 0;
            Stack<int> sum = new Stack<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < queries.Length; i++)
            {
                sum.Push(queries[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; sum.Count != 0; i++)
            {
                if(i != 0)
                {
                    sums += sum.Pop();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please add an attempt you have made and we will be glad to help. **HINT** You could use a recersive method or nested for loops, etc.

Comment: Added one of the attempts

Comment: @gunr2171 yea, I know how to do single array sum. But not this one :(

Comment: Kind of yea, tried to put it in some loop to do 2 times, but it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this much more efficiently and more easily, by multiplying each value by its reversed index + 1

For example, using LINQ

```cs
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 6 };
var result = arr.Reverse().Select((val, i) => val * (i + 1)).Sum();
```

Note that `.Reverse` on an array (or other `Collection<T>`) does not actually move any items, it just reads them backwards. So this is therefore an **O(n)** operation, as opposed to your original solution which is **O(n<sup>2</sup> / 2)**

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yjcl7J)

You can also do this procedurally, this is almost the same as [@aminrd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72888255/14868997).

```cs
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 6 };
var result = 0;
for (var i = arr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    result += arr[i] * (i + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks :) More efficient way

Answer (score 2):

You can run this task in a single loop considering when you have an array of size 5, the first element is repeating 5 times, second element repeating 4 times and etc.

```cs
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 6 };

int mysum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    mysum += (arr.Length - i) * arr[i];

Console.WriteLine(mysum);
```

Output:

```
31
```

Explanation:

```
1                 = 1
1 + 2             = 3
1 + 2 + 2         = 5
1 + 2 + 2 + 3     = 8
1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 6 = 14
========================
5*1 + 4*2 + 3*2 + 2*3 + 1*6 = 31
```

Comment: Ohh thanks. Could you explain to me, how it works? It looks a bit odd ... You are just multiplying index by a element?

Comment: @raicha I rewrite your expected sum and as you can see, first element is repeating 5 times (which is length of array minus index)  and etc.

Comment: Looping backwards would make more sense probably

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of Linq! `.Sum()` will add up everything in your collection. You run that twice, once per each slice, and once per each subtotal.

```
var input = new [] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 6 };
var totalSum = Enumerable.Range(1, input.Length).Sum(len => input[0..len].Sum());
// totalSum is 31
```

`Enumerable.Range` gets you a collection of numbers between (and including) 1 and 5 - the possible lengths of each slice of your sub arrays. You then use the range operator `[0..#]` to get increasingly larger slices.

Yes, this is not as clever as aminrd's solution - it's doing all the computations manually and you're performing many slices.

Comment: `input.Take(len).Sum()` would avoid slices (and possibly easier to read for old non-python folks).